# Issue with appending items in jQuery Masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to do a masonry layout with a bunch of tiles with some containing images. Here's roughly my code:

```
var $mainContent = $('#main-content');

$mainContent.imagesLoaded(function() {
  $mainContent.masonry()
});

loadMore = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/things',
    success: function (data) {
      var $data = $(data);
      $data.imagesLoaded(function() {
        $mainContent.append($data).masonry('appended', $data, true)
      })
    }
  })
}

$('#load-more').on('click', loadMore)
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error in Chrome's console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined
```

Trace:

```
bB jquery.min.js:2
f.each.f.cssHooks.(anonymous function).get jquery.min.js:4
f.extend.css jquery.min.js:4
f.each.f.fn.(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:4
e.extend.access jquery.min.js:2
f.each.f.fn.(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:4
f.each.f.fn.(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:4
$.Mason._placeBrick jquery.masonry.js:246
$.Mason.layout jquery.masonry.js:172
$.Mason._appended jquery.masonry.js:352
$.Mason.appended jquery.masonry.js:341
```

I'm using Masonry v.2.1.05 and jQuery v1.7.2

However, when I instead do `reload` instead of `appended`, it works like it does in the demos, but I want the posts to be populated from the bottom, and I don't want all the posts to be recalculated.

Do you know what's going on?

I also put this issue on [github](https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/213) but I haven't gotten a response yet.

Answer (score 7):

This was exactly what I need to have the animation and have various sized images render correctly:

```
var el = jQuery(html);
el.imagesLoaded(function() {
    $('#container').append(el).masonry( 'appended', el );
});
```

Comment: im getting this error `cannot call methods on masonry prior to initialization; attempted to call 'appended'`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is an answer to the problem but ... bear with me I'm thinking out loud here ...

Given that `.append($data)` appears *inside* the `$data.imagesLoaded` handler, it's not clear how that event would ever fire. I say that based on my understanding that the browser will not attempt to load images until the fragment based on `data` (presumably an HTML string) has been loaded into the DOM (with `.append()`).

The following would make more sense:

```
loadMore = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/things',
        success: function (data) {
            var $data = $(data);
            $data.imagesLoaded(function() {
                $mainContent.masonry('appended', $data, true);
            }).appendTo($mainContent);
        }
    });
};
```

That said, in your code the `imagesLoaded` event must fire otherwise why would you get the error? Maybe images *do* load into an unappended fragment!

Anyway, try my version. I guess it will either work or give the same error as before.

Comment: well it works if i simply change `masonry('appended', $data, true)` to `masonry('reload')` like i said in the question, so I supposed `imagesLoaded` is firing correctly. Also, `appendTo` is supposed to be before the `masonry` method according to the docs.

Comment: What happens if you try to run my version? Don't worry about the apparent order - it should execute as per the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution... this will surely work.

```
//Initiate your maosnry
$container = $('#container');
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){ 
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.item'
    }); 
});

//and on ajax call use this to append or prepend
$container.append($data).imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry( 'appended', $data, true );
});
```