# Masonry - Cannot call methods on masonry prior to initialization

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

I get the error:

```
cannot call methods on masonry prior to initialization; attempted to call 'appended'
```

I looked at various [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173442/issue-with-appending-items-in-jquery-masonry) regarding the issue and masonry's own [FAQ](http://masonry.desandro.com/faq.html#call-methods-error).

I implemented the suggested fixes but no luck, I get the same error, I even went back to basics and did this:

```
imagesLoaded(this.galleryGrid, function(instance) {
        var msnry = new Masonry('.grid', {
            itemSelector: '.item',
            columnWidth: '.item'
        });

        var $newElems = $('.test').clone();
        $('.grid').masonry('appended', $newElems );

    });
```

I still get the same error. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
 imagesLoaded(this.galleryGrid, function(instance) {
    var msnry = new Masonry('.grid', {
        itemSelector: '.item',
        columnWidth: '.item'
    });

    var $newElems = $('.test').clone();
    $('.grid').append( $newElems ).masonry('appended', $newElems );

  });
```